# Calling REST web service when user type in textbox

Tags: javascript, html

I created search service like `http://localhost/data/search?keyword=samsung black` and it gives me search result for samsung black Json data like

```
[
    {
        "id": "5344e2a6f95dc373d6707ec1",
        "category": "Electronics",
        "lowestLevelFeild": "Mobile & phones",
        "searchKeyword": "samsung black",
        "autoSelectedFields": [
            "samsung"
        ]
    }
]
```

I am trying to call this service from html client.I want when user type in text field it should listed above search results(lowestLevelFeild)like autocomplete.I can use Jquery autocomplete plugin. My query is how  I call above service as soon as user type in text field so that autocomplete results change according to input?

Comment: Where is your code so far?

Comment: Use jQuery's input callback to receive an event when the user starts typing. In this event, use AJAX to connect to your service to get the JSON response. Populate the autocomplete with the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [*input* event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/input), example (**[working here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZEfEy/)**):

```
<input id="q" name="q">
<div id="r"></div>
<script>
 $('#q').on('input',function(e){$('#r').text(e.target.value)});
</script>
```

And you can see input event + jquery autocomplete **[here](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote)**.